# Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL error: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I am trying to have image upload feature but I am getting an error "Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL error: unhashable type: 'dict'". I am using `react-dropzone` for uploading the image. It gives me File object which i then passed in mutation function with variables. Here is what, i have done

mutation.py

```
class UpdatePersonalProfile(graphene.Mutation):

    class Arguments:
        input = ProfileInput(description="These fields are required", required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()
    errors = graphene.List(graphene.String)
    profile = graphene.Field(ProfileNode)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(self, info, **args):
        print ('info', args, info.context, info.context.FILES, info.context.FILES.get(args.get('input').get('avatar', None)))
        is_authenticated = info.context.user.is_authenticated
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=CustomUser.objects.get(id=7))
        profile.company_name = args.get('input').get('company_name', None)
        profile.bio = args.get('input').get('bio', None)
        profile.website = args.get('input').get('website', None)
        profile.avatar = info.context.FILES.get(args.get('input').get('avatar', None))
        profile.job_title = args.get('input').get('job_title', None)
        profile.zip_code = args.get('input').get('zip_code', None)
        profile.save()
        return UpdatePersonalProfile(profile=profile, success=True, errors=None)
```

input.py

```
class Upload(graphene.types.Scalar):

    class Meta:
        description = '''Variables of this type must be set to null in
        mutations. They will be replaced with a filename from a following
        multipart part containing a binary file. See:
        https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec'''

    @staticmethod
    def serialize(value):
        return value

    @staticmethod
    def parse_literal(node):
        return node

    @staticmethod
    def parse_value(value):
        return value

class ProfileInput(graphene.InputObjectType):

    full_name = graphene.String(description='Full Name')
    user = graphene.String(description='User')
    bio = graphene.String(description='No more than 1000 characters')
    website = graphene.String()
    avatar = Upload(description='Avatar')
    job_title = graphene.String()
    company_name = graphene.String()
    zip_code = graphene.String()
```

Here is the data for avatar key where i have used files[0] that means whole File object.

[image]

How do i upload image when using django-graphene?

Comment: Could you provide stack trace to figure out which part is broken?

Answer (score 0):

Here is good package I used and pretty satisfied: [graphene-file-upload](https://github.com/lmcgartland/graphene-file-upload)

It handles multipart data and replaces actual variables with passed files.